# HTML clock snippet not working in Safari, but working in Chrome

Tags: html

I have a code that I'm using [here](http://workingholidaystudio.com/home) from 24timezones to create a cute little clock. However, it only works on Chrome and not Safari. Is there a reason for this?

```html
<a href="https://24timezones.com" style="text-decoration: none" class="clock24" id="tz24-1618903128-c1137-eyJob3VydHlwZSI6IjEyIiwic2hvd2RhdGUiOiIwIiwic2hvd3NlY29uZHMiOiIwIiwic2hvd3RpbWV6b25lIjoiMSIsInR5cGUiOiJkIiwibGFuZyI6ImVuIn0=" title="what time is now" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//w.24timezones.com/l.js" async></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly does this not work in safari?

Comment: Even if we were to find out the reason, the terms of use you agreed to when you chose to use the widget means you can't change the code of the widget. https://24timezones.com/clock-widget/text (click the "Widgets Terms of Use" link).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure it out.